# Constructing reducible polynomial with two irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials, plane-curves, polynomial-rings

I'm currently trying to prove following statement.

Let f,g be homogeneous polynomials of degree n,m respectively, in $k[X,Y,Z]$.
Here k is algebraically closed field, and n $\le$ m. Also f does not divide g.
Then there exists a homogeneous polynomial h with degree m-n such that fh+g is reducible.

I proved this in the case m=2 or n=1. Mainly I used Bezout's theorem for proof. However, this doesn't work well for higher degrees. I personally believe that this statement should be true. In the sense that irreducible element is prime element in UFD, if fh+g is always irreducible, then we will get infinitely many prime elements by using method.

Please give me any type of advice to help proving this statement.

Comment: Suppose $f=X$ and $g=Y$, so $m=n=1$. Then you're alleging there is a constant $h$ such that $hX+Y$ is reducible.

Comment: As Gerry Myerson has pointed out, $m=1,n=1$, this will fail. If $m=2, n\leq 2$, this is correct. But, $m=3, n=3$ this will fail too. The idea is to look at all homogeneous polynomials of degree 3, which forms a 9 dimensional projective space. The reducible ones have dimension 7, so you can find a line not meeting this set and that gives you what you want. (Same argument for $m=n\geq 3$).

Comment: Thank both for Gerry Myerson and Mohan. I haven't thought about the space of cubic. May I ask one more question? For conic, we can use bilinear form and its determinant (as a matrix) to prove whether it is irreducible or not. Is there same thing for higher degree curves?

Comment: For any homogeneous polynomial $F(X,Y,Z)$, if $F_X,F_Y,F_Z$ have no non-trivial common zeroes (in characteristic zero), then $F=0$ is smooth and thus irreducible. This condition is not necessary in general for irreducibility, but for quadratic polynomials, this is also necessary, which leads to the criterion you stated above.

Comment: So every irreducible conic is smooth, but not generally true for higher degrees. Thanks! You helped me much :)